# Error When Trying Run SQL Server Query through Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

My application is building successfully but won't run the query. Here's what I've done so far:

- Downloaded JDBC Driver and used to successfully create connection to database, which is showing in services tab
- Added CLASSPATH variable and added C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;.;C:\Program Files\Java\Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.4 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_7.4\enu\mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar as well as my JRE and JDK bin folders and .
- Run below code

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestCode {




   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

       try {
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

       String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://mysqlserver:1433;databaseName=mydatabase;integratedSecurity=false;";

       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password") ;  
       Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs;

       rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 10 UserID FROM dbo.Users");
       while (rs.next())
       {
           String userID = rs.getString("UserID");
           System.out.println(userID);
       }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           System.err.println("Error");
           System.err.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

Error
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Which is the just the name of my driver. I got this from right clicking on the driver, clicking customize and copying the Driver Class from this Window.

Comment: Not related but **do not** use `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`

Comment: Thanks, that's not actually the code I'm going to run though. I just put anything in there as a test that it would actually return something

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Needed to add JDBC driver file to project library